# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error que sale en la consola?

Tags: javascript, html

Me aparece el siguiente error en la consola  muestro el error

[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.

Lo que trato de hacer es editar mis registros en una base de datos de una agenda con ajax

mando mi código de html

```
                          <td>
                                         <a class="btn-editar btn" href="editar.php?id=<?php $contacto['id']; ?>">
                                              <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>
                                         </a>
                                         <button data-id="<?php $contacto['id']; ?>" type="button" class="btn-borrar btn">
                                              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                         </button>
                                    </td>
```

Gracias de antemano

```
if(respuesta) {
           // llamado a ajax
           // crear el objeto
           const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

           // abrir la conexión
           xhr.open('GET', `inc/modelos/modelo-contactos-eliminar.php?id=${id}&accion=borrar`, true);
           // leer la respuesta
           xhr.onload = function() {
                if(this.status === 200) {
                     const resultado = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  
                     if(resultado.respuesta === 'correcto') {

                          // Eliminar el registro del DOM
                          e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();

                          // mostrar Notificación
                          mostrarNotificacion('Paciente eliminado', 'correcto');

                     } else {
                          // Mostramos una notificacion
                          mostrarNotificacion('Paciente no eliminado', 'error' );
                     }

                }
           }

           // enviar la petición
           xhr.send();
      }
 }
```

}

Comment: Coloca tu código de javascript

Comment: añadido.......!

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `console.log(id)` antes de abrir la conexión, para saber que tipo de dato es id?

Comment: Borre parte de mi codigo para hacer el console.log(id) y me marca el mismo id el que le puse al html estatico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta declarar una variable que incluya la ruta con los parámetros y esto será lo que envias

```
let route = `inc/modelos/modelo-contactos-eliminar.php?id=${id}&accion=borrar`);

// Encode solamente en el id
let routeId = encodeURIComponent(id);
let route = `inc/modelos/modelo-contactos-eliminar.php?id=${routeId}&accion=borrar`);

xhr.open('GET', route, true);
```

Comment: ya se fue la advertencia pero tengo este error app.js:176 GET http://localhost:8888/Agenda/inc%2Fmodelos%2Fmodelo-contactos-eliminar.php%3Fid%3D%26accion%3Dborrar 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada, tal vez necesites hacer encode en el id

Comment: Listo! , pero me marca el siguiente error VM480:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Comment: aqui es donde muestra el error const resultado = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);